# Can I use two DC-DC Converter modules to generate a +5V and -5V Rail?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter

These converters from Pololu look great (https://www.pololu.com/product/2831), but I need both a positive and negative rail. Can I use two of these to make a +5V and -5V rail? For example. if I tie the + terminal on one to the - terminal on the other and tie that node to ground and then use the respective output terminals as +/-5V rails, would that work?

Comment: A similar question which explains why the answer is "NO": [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/117473/5542](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/117473/5542)

Comment: There are also modules which output both rails, although much less common. Random example found with google: https://www.reichelt.com/?LANGUAGE=EN&CTYPE=0&MWSTFREE=0&CCOUNTRY=447&ARTICLE=159015&PROVID=2788&wt_guka=22596717017_79177296617&PROVID=2788&gclid=CKjr17rE0s0CFVQ_GwodkpEO6A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is not the way you have described: these are non-isolated converters.

As you can see in the picture (from the web site), there is a single ground pin (for both input and output).

[image: Converter power pins]

To achieve what you want to do you can either use isolated converters *or* you can use two of them in this manner: use one to get 5V; power the second one from this 5V to get a [negative output](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/DN05004-D.PDF) provided your total load is within the current allowed from the first regulator.

[image: Negative regulator from buck]

As these are rated for 36V you should be fine - the second regulator will see an effective 10V in to out.

I made a picture of two regulators showing how I would hook them up for +5V and -5V:

[image: Using two bucks for dual polarity supplly]

Hopefully that is clear.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. So the first dc-dc GND should not be connected to a common ground that all other components will share, right? It effectively floats with no connection? The second dc-dc's vout node becomes the ground for all components?

Comment: The first converter ground *is* connected to the common ground and the second supply uses *its positive output* as ground.

Comment: We are happy to help with real issues. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [schematic](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J843/d24v10fx-schematic.pdf) of this converter. If you do what you suggest, it means you tie the 5V output of the second converter to ground, thus shorting it.

So, no, since they are not isolated, you can't wire these converters as you suggest. You need *isolated* converters to do this. Isolated converters have a transformer that allows this.

Or another option would be to use a non-isolated *inverter* DC-DC converter. They are easy to find and would be cheaper and smaller than isolated ones, I think (There are none on polulu, it seems, though. Try mouser/digikey).

Answer (score 2):

No you can't because that would **short circuit** the - 5 V converter as the input ground and the output ground are the same node.

It actually has only one connection pin !

What you need is a regulator with an **isolated output** for the -5 V. Then the output is floating and you can use it to make - 5V. Some examples of these are [here](http://www.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=2002&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T&paramCriteria=no).